# Alternative to / Migrate from Umbraco 5

Tags: umbraco

what other CMS would be the best option if I want to migrate from umbraco 5?
I want to use the code from umbraco as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I migrated an Umbraco v5 website back to Umbraco 4.7.2 and all-in-all it was a rather painless process - lots of my razor scripts were easily ported back. After struggling to get things working acceptably with v5 for weeks, it was actually quite refreshing to use a proven CMS again and the performance improvement was outstanding.

Personally I am rather disappointed with the way the whole v5 debacle played out, but all-in-all it was probably the best and only way forward given the challenges they were facing with the new codebase.

Comment: what about options other than umbraco?

Answer (score 0):

sudhirk why do you want to leave umbraco?

I wouldn't be put off by what umbraco hq have decided to do with V5 in face its does nothing but strengthen my love of umbraco, umbraco is a brilliant (FREE!!!) cms but what is really great about it, is the forum community. Any questions you have, pop them in there, they will get answered.

Thanks,
Will